# ¿Tamaño maximo de un arreglo?

Tags: c++, array

Resulta que necesito guardar al menos 3628800 elementos en un array pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo en c++ . No sé si debo usar un unsigned int o un unsigned long int. Muchas gracias por su atención

Answer (score 1):

Debes distinguir entre un tipo de datos y un arreglo.

El tipo de datos determina cuánto ocupa el valor de una variable en memoria.

Al declarar un arreglo le estás diciendo al compilador que quieres almacenar una cantidad fija de elementos en memoria. Por ello se declaran indicando un tipo de datos y una cantidad fija de elementos.

---

Ya tienes en claro que necesitas un arreglo, pero ¿De qué elementos? Eso lo verás según lo que busques.

¿Quieres almacenar números enteros?

- Puedes usar `short`, `int`, `long` y otros. Cuál elegir depende de qué tan grande sean los números que quieres guardar.

¿Quieres almacenar números reales?

- Puedes usar `float`, `double` o `long double`.

Puedes ver una lista de los tipos básicos de C++ [aquí](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).

---

Puedes declarar un arreglo lo haces de las siguientes maneras:

```
Tipo nombre[] = Tipo[n];

Tipo nombre[n];
```

También puedes indicar los elementos que quieres que tenga, enumerandolos entre llaves y separados por coma:

```
int numeros[] = { 3, 1, 8, 10 };
```

El problema que podrías tener es que te quedes corto de memoria porque no hay espacio para tantos números. Cada tipo tiene ocupa una cantidad diferente de memoria.